# Can only assign functions to scope inside directive in controller function, not link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've just run into an issue where it seems that I can only assign functions to scope and execute them if I do it inside the controller function of a directive, but not in link. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbx979prPBWU1AqFP478) example here.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('linkDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="press()">Link</button><p>{{ linkmsg  }}</p>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.press = function(){
        scope.linkmsg = 'link function executed'
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('controllerDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="press()">Controller</button><p>{{ controllermsg  }}</p>',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.press = function(){
        $scope.controllermsg = 'controller function executed';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <link-dir></link-dir>
    <controller-dir></controller-dir>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both directives add a function named `press()` to the same scope. So the last one to execute wins, and overwrites the `press()` function added to the scope by the previous one. Use distinct names, and both will work:

```
app.directive('linkDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="press1()">Link</button><p>{{ linkmsg  }}</p>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.press1 = function(){
        scope.linkmsg = 'link function executed'
      }
    }
  };
});

app.directive('controllerDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="press2()">Controller</button><p>{{ controllermsg  }}</p>',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.press2 = function(){
        $scope.controllermsg = 'controller function executed';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sKeQbFILJMKQ6B70tsnY?p=preview

Comment: Ah, you're quite right. Just a mistake I made in the plunkr. There must be a separate issue in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Posting another question